# Upgrading sql server database that is being mirrored - how to?

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

OK so I've been tasked with upgrading an application which involves updating schema in a sql server 2005.  Now I've been told their dr environment has a mirrored database.  I've read the msdn article on mirroring but am unclear how it impacts my upgrade.

Do I:
a) want to stop the mirroring (someone mentioned a wizard, but I'm not sure how I go about doing this)
b) keep the mirroring in place because whatever I run on the primary database will flow through to the mirror

If I stop the mirroring do I then upgrade each database according to my scripts and then somehow set up the mirroring again?  Or do I just apply my scripts to the primary database and do some kind of restore and set that up as a mirror.

As it is an existing mirror in a production environment I don't want to poke around too much in case I do something bad.  Is there an easy way to grab their current settings so I can easily re-establish the mirror if I do have to stop it?

Thanks!

Edit - my other question is, with the transaction logs it looks like its being backed up every 15 minutes according to a schedule.  Should I change the backup schedule whilst doing the deployment?  I think one of my redgate schema changes scripts will take over 2 hours to run :)  It is a big database!

Comment: Please provide more detail about what you're doing - is it just the schema that is changing, or are there other data model changes (in addition to that)?

Comment: I'll be generating and using a redgate script to update the schema of the database. But I imagine there will also be data changes as I set up the configuration properties of this application (which get stored in the database). There is a primary server which is mirrored to a second server. The primary server has its transaction logs being shipped to a third server. The third server contains a read only database that is on standby for their DR environment. So do I need to pause or remove mirroring? And will it automatically apply changes to all three servers? :) Thanks!

Comment: By schema changes (in case I'm using the wrong terminology).  I'll be synchronising the data structure of tables and associated constraints, and updating stored procedures.  There's about 8 scripts that I'll be running.  Some of which are just structural, but others are content changes to data.

Comment: Also I'm not concerned about the mirror being available or anything whilst the upgrade is taking place.

Though if it all goes horribly wrong - I will need to restore the primary database which will then hopefully get updated to the other two servers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anything you do on the principal will be mirrored on the Mirror.
 so yes, you just update the schema on the principal and that's it.